# Solving a first order ODE with proper substatution.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Hi guys I am really stuck on solving this first order ODE.

$$y'=t^{20}y+\cos(t^{14})$$

What I have tried so far was substitutions to make the equation more manageable things such as $u=t^7$ hoping that will clear the $cos$ and then use integration factor, but it did not work. Still when I look at the problem it seems as a simple substitution should work, but I do not know just speculate.

I am honestly what type problem this is as in what approach to will yield results. I would really appreciate some help.

Comment: Do you know the method with integrating factor? If so, then try it! (You might end up with the solution expressed as an integral)

Comment: @mickep but how to go about solving that difficult integral